# WinRT and software ClearType font rendering

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, cleartype, windows-runtime

Does WinRT provides an option to fall back to software ClearType font rendering (as Direct2D do via "Direct2D and GDI Interoperability") or we will be stuck with somewhat blurry hardware font anti-aliasing only?

Comment: No GDI in WinRT, DirectWrite is it.  High DPI panels for everyone, yahoo.

Comment: @Hans DirectWrite still has the option to fall back to "GDI classic" antialiasing, but I don't think that's exposed in Windows.UI.Xaml.

Comment: Pavel is probably right.

Comment: There is no visual difference between software and hardware sub-pixel ClearType rendering.  I think perhaps you are referring to regular gray-scale (smoothing) vs ClearType.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612266/why-cant-directx-directwrite-direct2d-text-rendering-be-as-sharp-as-gdi/8663198#8663198

Answer (score 2):

No. Windows on ARM will not support ClearType. This is by design.

Instead, Windows on ARM tablets will be required to have a high DPI.

- http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120303/cleartype-takes-a-back-seat-for-windows-8-metro/

Comment: Which is stupid, because for the first many years 99% of all Windows 8  Metro users will be on the desktop and they'll have to suffer for this stupidity.

Comment: I wasn't commenting on whether it was a good idea, merely that it is by design. Note that Windows on ARM is tablet only. Windows8 Desktop will still have ClearType.

Comment: Oh I know. I'm just venting. I'm not sure I understood your comment correctly, going by Zheng's article, Metro apps on Windows 8 PCs will also not have ClearType, no?

Comment: In Windows8 on the desktop, the start screen and all metro apps will not have ClearType, but desktop applications will. In Windows on ARM (WinRT), ClearType is globally disabled.