# Win SDK misses OpenGL functions glStencilOpSeparate and glStencilFuncSeparate

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I'm using WinSDK v10.0.22621.0 but it has no functions glStencilOpSeparate and glStencilFuncSeparate. These OpenGL functions should be available in OpenGL v2, v3, and v4 according to [documentation](https://docs.gl/gl4/glStencilOpSeparate). But I can't find functions declarations in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\gl\GL.h` and can't find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64\OpenGL32.Lib` from WinSDK.

I'm using Windows 11 and functions `glStencilOpSeparate`, `glStencilFuncSeparate` are not available in `C:\windows\System32\OpenGL32.dll`. I checked list of export functions for this DLL and found only `glStencilOp` and `glStencilFunc`.

Why these functions are not available?

Comment: Use an OpenGL loader like [gelw](https://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/)

Comment: MS doesn't support OpenGL anymore (in favor of its own API Direct3D). Nevertheless, you can use OpenGL until recent standard as the GPU drivers usually provide the OpenGL API. You just have to bind the driver functions to function pointers to use them as usual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are GDI, GDI+ and OpenGL really obsolete/deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007789/are-gdi-gdi-and-opengl-really-obsolete-deprecated)