# Technical reasons to not allow using UI part of WinRT API in regular desktop applications

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

WinRT API can be called from applications other than Metro style applications, except XAML classes. It might be beneficial to use some controls on desktop. What are the technical problems causing this restriction?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475775/winrt-and-build-in-windows-8-apps

Comment: The fact that a Metro Syle app does not use windows handles may have something to do with it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it would be possible, but it would be too much work both from MS and the developers using this.

If you have some GUI library, I don't really see the benefit of using WinRT `Button` over the built-in button component.

Comment: The Benefit would come if MS would finally produce a good GUI library and not something like the MFC shit from 1990.